# Converting date string to date

Tags: php, string, date

I'm trying to use `strtotime` to convert date strings in the format `Jan 14th 2011` to the format `2011-01-14` but it's not working.

Is this format not suitable for `strtotime` and if so, how can I convert it. The month is always in 3-letter format, like Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec

Comment: I think it's not !! You have to change your input date format !!

Comment: I tested here and it works just fine. date("Y-m-d",strtotime("Jan 14th 2011")) = "2011-01-14" I don't see the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working"?  do you get an error? or is the conversion incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$date_str = "Jan 14th 2011";
$date = date_parse_from_format('M jS Y', $date_str);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Heh, it's like you read my mind (except I had used `DateTime::createFromFormat()`).

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

AFAIK, strtotime parses an English textual date or time into a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime or solutions like that would need a little bit of changes for each use case. If you want to go a little bit further and have a permanent solution to convert raw string dates into time formats you can check this project I did https://github.com/raimonbosch/date.extraction I'm using regular grammars to detect all kind of date formats.

Comment: When you link to your own project you should disclose the fact that it's your project. From the FAQ: "However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers. "