# Date functions in PHP

Tags: php, date

Another simple question. I found this really cool snippet of code:

```
$date_str = "Jan 14th 2011";
$date = date_parse_from_format('M jS Y', $date_str);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

But when I run it on my computer it says Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object line 3.

The code was taken from here [Converting date string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606329/converting-date-string-to-date) so I presume it is good but it looks like it is referencing to an object that does not exist.

I have been looking at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp amongst many others but I have not found any any clues.

My question is should this code work as a standalone piece of code. If so why does it not work for me? Else, should I do to get it to work as expected.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?  That function is for PHP >= 5.3.0 whereas most shared hosting companies still provide PHP 4 by default.  Check `phpinfo()`.

Comment: @jedwards thank you again. In this case I am using PHP Version 5.3.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date_parse_from_format();
```

returns associative array and you are trying to access the class method on a non object.

if you want to make use of PHP's inbuilt DateTime class. then more information here https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: that works. Just a quick question is there an easy way for me to check it will convert to a date without creating an exception if it fails?

Comment: exceptions are meant to be thrown when something fails, if you want the exception part to be skipped then bind it by using try catch statement. for example `try { /***your datetime code here***/ } catch(Exception $e) {  /*** do whatever with the caught exception, leaving it empty will not show you the exeption ***/  }` having said this, it is always good to check for errors or warnings. i wouldn't reccomend this, or you can log the error into a file in catch statement instead of displaying it back to user.

Answer (score 2):

date_parse_from_format returns an array, not a DateTime object. What you want is

```
$date = date_create_from_format('M jS Y', $date_str);
             ^^^^^^---note the change
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```